# Discriminant for system of quadratic equations

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, polynomials

A quadratic equation $$a x^2 + b x + c = 0 $$ with real coefficients $a,b,c$ has a real solution $x\in\mathbb R$ if and only if the discriminant $$b^2- 4 a c \ge 0 $$ is non-negative.

Can something similar be said for a system of two quadratic equations of the form \begin{align}
a_{xx} x^2 + a_{xy} x y + b_x x + c & = 0\\
a_{yx } y x + a_{yy } y^2 + b_y y + c & = 0
\end{align} in terms of the coefficient matrix $a$, the coefficient vector $b$ and the scalar coefficient $c$? For symmetry it might be helpful the assume $a$ to be symmetric and $b$ to be constant. Is there a multidimensional quantity generalizing the discriminant? All I could find were generalizations of the discriminant to higher order polynomials.

Comment: 1) The "natural" generalization of the discriminant is what is called the resultant, but usually it is with a single variable (it expresses the fact that two equations have at least a common root) 2) The example you take with the intersection of two conic sections is not the most general: there should be a "$b_{xx}$ term (coefficient of $y^2$) and a $b_y$ term (coefficient of $y$)